# Can a Google Cloud Function knows its trigger endpoint?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a GCF written in Python 3.7, I'm trying to get the trigger endpoint url from within the function itself.

I need the function to comunicate its url to other systems, programmatically.

Am I in luck? is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you referring to the HTTP trigger endpoint?

Comment: yes Nickson. I'm looking for a way to get the HTTP trigger endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```py
import os

def get_url(request):
    return request.url_root + os.environ['X_GOOGLE_FUNCTION_NAME']
```

Comment: holly cow! that makes a lot of sense, how didn't i though of that.! Thanks Dustin!

Comment: Unfortunately it _should_ be simpler (just `request.base_url`) but Cloud Functions has an unfortunate bug/feature where it strips the function name from the request.

Comment: Since October 2021, I cannot longer see `X_GOOGLE_FUNCTION_NAME` env variable. 
According [to the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#runtime_environment_variables_set_automatically), `FUNCTION_NAME` env variable should do the work

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to construct the url from the `environ` dictionary:

```
def get_url(request):

    env = request.__dict__['environ'] 
    return "https://{}-{}.cloudfunctions.net/{}".format(env['X_GOOGLE_FUNCTION_REGION'], env['GCP_PROJECT'], env['X_GOOGLE_FUNCTION_NAME'])
```